# While developing for iOS can viewcontroller classes be marked final if we do not want to subclass them?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Is marking viewcontroller classes final good thing to do  for performance benefits if we do not want to subclass them?

Comment: according to your requirement, you should Definitely do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing class or function, which  logically can't be override or don't want to be subclassed by another developer it's better to mark is at final.

from apple documentation:

> You can prevent a method, property, or subscript from being overridden by marking it as final. Do this by writing the final modifier before the method, property, or subscript’s introducer keyword (such as final var, final func, final class func, and final subscript).
>
> Any attempt to override a final method, property, or subscript in a subclass is reported as a compile-time error. Methods, properties, or subscripts that you add to a class in an extension can also be marked as final within the extension’s definition.
>
> You can mark an entire class as final by writing the final modifier before the class keyword in its class definition (final class). Any attempt to subclass a final class is reported as a compile-time error.